# Select Data from xml column based on multiple condition

Tags: sql, xml

I have table with xml column, need to search data across the table

Structure of xml row

```
<Employees>
 <Emp>
   <Name>Adam</Name>
   <Department>Accounts</Department>
   <Active>1</Active>
 </Emp>
  <Emp>
   <Name>John</Name>
   <Department>Marketing</Department>
   <Active>0</Active>
 </Emp>
  <Emp>
   <Name>Steve</Name>
   <Department>Marketing</Department>
   <Active>1</Active>
 </Emp>
  <Emp>
   <Name>Michel</Name>
   <Department>Marketing</Department>
   <Active>0</Active>
 </Emp>
  <Emp>
   <Name>Joe</Name>
   <Department>Accounts</Department>
   <Active>1</Active>
 </Emp>
</Employees>
```

I want to check if exists in xml dept = accounts and active is 1

Answer (score 0):

```
.exist('.//Emp[Department/text()[contains(., "Accounts")] and Active/text()[contains(., "1")]]')
```